# How to integrate Qt with ROS?

Tags: qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to use an QT as an user interface for my mobile platform. I have a sensor package consist of IMU , Laser, Kinect and wheel encoders.  Would like to have an input button that run a rose node than do some classification with SVM and output button with some classification results. Any help or advice, or code suggestion regarding this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103011/how-to-integrate-qt-with-ros-?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just build you app using whatever pieces of Qt you need then tie to ROS as follows.
Add the `find_package(Qt COMPONENTS ... REQUIRED)` in your `CMakeLists.txt` file and  the appropriate lines for moc and resource files as needed. For example;

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

file(GLOB QT_FORMS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.ui)
file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS *.h)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})
QT4_WRAP_UI(QT_FORMS_HPP ${QT_FORMS})
```

And link as needed

```
add_executable([some_binary] ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})

target_link_libraries([some_binary] ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ... ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-11-24**:
Sorry but Im totally new in Qt. So from where should I start?Do I start from the ROS side first or??Can you tell me a bit more and in a simple way as im totally new in this?Can you expand the answer in like simple steps are needed?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another option is to write a [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) plugin as described in the [rqt tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials) (using either Python or C++). This allows you to embed your UI with other rqt widgets easily.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-11-20**:
So whats the difference between them?Is it possible to ingrate SVM and other machine learning methods into it?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-21**:
You can add anything you want to your UI plugins. If such tight coupling of machine learning code into a UI widget makes sense depends on the application, however.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-11-21**:
Ok. thanks. Thats helps a lot. Any example or some tutorial in the web world (outside ROS) regarding these?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-11-21**:
@Astronaut that sounds like a whole new question; I thought you were asking about mobile UI. It would be interesting, however, to try using Qt for mobile, since I've not seen anybody tried that in rqt.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-11-21**:
What do you mean a whole new question @IsaacSaito ? Im trying to have an UI that is deployed on a mobile platform. Why I can not use QT for mobile platform like robotics wheelchair?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-11-21**:
Nevermind, I think I took your statement wrong (thought you started mentioning about web interface), but again, I'm curious about how rqt on mobile works.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-11-21**:
No. Its not web interface. I will try the first option building the application using Qt and than tie to ROS,.See hows going